# Redux toolkit action is stuck in pending state even after api response is recieved

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I am using redux toolkit and all of the other actions for slice are working as expected but only editCountry action has problem. My editCountry action is stuck in country/editCountry/pending. I have no idea what is wrong with code.

This is how redux slice code is defined.
slice.js

```
const initialState = {
    countries: {},
    isLoading: false,
    isError: false,
    isSuccess: false,
    message: ''
}

export const editCountry = createAsyncThunk(
    'country/editCountry',
    async (payload, thunkAPI) => {
        try {
            const response = await apiProvider.editCountry(payload);
            return response;
        }
        catch (e) {
            return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(e)
        }
    })

const countriesSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'country',
    initialState,
    reducers: { },
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
      builder
             .addCase(editCountry.pending, (state, action) => {
                state.isLoading = true
            })
            .addCase(editCountry.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                console.log('fulfilled before: ', state); // shown on console
                console.log('fulfilled action: ', action.payload.data); // undefined
                const unUpdatedCountries = state.countries.data.filter(c => c._id !== 
                  action.payload.data._id)
                const updatedCountries  = [action.payload.data, ...unUpdatedCountries];

                state.isLoading = false;
                state.isSuccess = true;
                state.countries = {...state.countries, data: updatedCountries };
                console.log('fulfilled after: ', state);  // do not shown on console

            })
            .addCase(editCountry.rejected, (state, action) => {
                state.isLoading = false;
                state.isError = true;
                state.message = action.payload;
            })
    }
```

Here is the Api helper method which is invoked inside editCountry action.
ApiProvider.js

```
export const editCountry = async (payload) => {
    let token = getToken();
    const config = {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Accept: "application/json",
        },
    };

    try{
        const {data} = await axios.put(`${baseUrl}/edit-country`, payload, config);
        if(data.status){
            return Promise.resolve(data);
        }
        return Promise.reject(data.message);
    }
    catch (e) {
        return Promise.reject(e.message);
    }
}
```

And here is my Submit method from where action is dispatched.
Country.js

```
const handleSubmit = async (e, newFormData) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const apiPayload = {
            Country_ID: newFormData.id,
            Name: newFormData.name,
            DialCode: newFormData.dialCode.includes("+") ? newFormData.dialCode : "+"+newFormData.dialCode,
            ISO: newFormData.iso,
            CallRate: newFormData.minutePrice,
            Blocked: newFormData.isBlocked.value,
        }
        try {
            await dispatch(editCountry(apiPayload)).unwrap()
            toggle()    // hide form modal
            toast.success('Country updated successfully');
        }
        catch (e) {
            setFormData({
                ...formData,
                errorMsg: e.message,
            });
            toggle();
            toast.error(e);
        }
    }
```

On action dispatch redux is stuck on pending but in network tab api call is completed.
[enter image description here][1]

Network tab image:
[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3rbA.png][1]

Redux dev tools image:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQUdJ.png

Answer (score 0):

Just return the data, don't return wrap it in Promise.resolve.

```
if(data.status){
            return Promise.resolve(data);
        }
        return Promise.reject(data.message);
}
```

---

In `editCountry.fulfilled`, it should be `action.payload` not `action.payload.data`.

In `editCountry`, you send `data` and in `editCountry async thunk`, you send the complete response which is basically the data. In `editCountry.fulfilled`, you have complete data in payload but you are trying to access the data from payload.

Hope this solve your issue

Comment: Thanks for quick answer Actually axios returns api response in `data`. Then my node js api has structure like this which I recieved in `editCountry async thunk` response
`{ status: true, message: "Country updated successfully", date: {…} }`. So this is complete object which I expect in `action.payload`.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check it. You are wrapping your data in Promise.resolve(). You should just return it.

Comment: Console the value in `editCountry async thunk` and check what you get.

Comment: Thanks @Nouman I figured out there was a typo I was accessing `data` but there was typo in api response. My bad

Comment: @Tayyab No Problem

Comment: Also you should generally `throw data.message` or `throw new Error(data.message)` instead of `return Promise.reject(data.message);`

Comment: `throw new Error(data.message)`.